# jQuery .find() not working in Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm retrieving [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) data with jQuery's `.ajax()` in my program.

All's merry in Internet Explorer 9, Chrome, Firefox and [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29).

There is an issue in [Internet Explorer 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7) and [Internet Explorer 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8).

My jQuery code is as follows.

```
$j.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    datatype:'HTML',
    url:processUrl,
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
        var testdata = $j(data).find(".category-products");
        alert(testdata.html());
        $j(".col-main .category-products").empty().replaceWith(testdata);
    },
    complete: function(){
        //Doing something
    }
});
```

Now, when I alert `data`, I get my HTML data (in Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8 as well).

But, when I alert `testdata`, I get `null` in Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8.

How can I go about solving this issue?

You can have a look at the error [here](http://amalageeks.com/Bakestore/index.php/tools.html) (hit the numbers for pagination) -

If you're debugging, then you'll find my code at line 11949. The script file will have a long weird name as it's merging other script files at runtime.

**UPDATE**

I implemented the same solution on localhost, and it's working fine on all browsers. Is it a server issue?

**UPDATE 2**

The issue has been solved, I'm guessing it was a caching issue on the server, because I installed a fresh copy of my project in a different location and it's working fine in all browsers.

Comment: Hve you tried alert( $(testdata).html() ); ?

Comment: Check this response, it worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12057929/15329

Answer (score 2):

```
success:function(data){
       alert(data);
       var temp = $j('<div/>').append(data); // Here is the trick:
                                             // Set the data to a
                                             // temporary element.
       var testdata = $j(temp ).find(".category-products"); // Then find
       alert(testdata.html());
       ...
 },
```

If the above don't work, then take a `hidden` div. Suppose:

```
<div id="imhidden"></div>
```

Then do following:

```
success:function(data){
        alert(data);
        $j('#imhidden').html(data); // Here is the trick:
                                    // Set the data to that
                                    // hidden div.

        var testdata = $j('#imhidden').find(".category-products"); // Then find
        alert(testdata.html());
        ...
},
```

Comment: @Tarun no, no problem for any browsers

Comment: Ok, just trying your solution now.

Comment: Not working, still get `null` when I alert. Working fine in other browsers

Comment: I've added a link to my work, please have a look. Hope it helps

Comment: The issue has been solved, I'm guessing it was a caching issue on the server, 'coz I installed a fresh copy of my project in a different location and it's working fine in all browsers