# IE 8 JQuery .find() not working on XML string

Tags: jquery, xml, soap, internet-explorer-8, find

JQuery does not seem to be able to find my selector string inside of a returned XML string. It **appears** to be working in Chrome, but I can't debug in the same environment due to browser authentication issues.

I know these type of questions have been asked in the past, but I haven't found anything that specifically applies to my situation.

The following XML response is supplied from a SOAP request; I believe the `<z:row` piece is what matters here:

```
"<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetListItemsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"><GetListItemsResult><listitems xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
                <rs:data ItemCount="6">
                    <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_Year="2012" ows_LinkTitle="Orange" ows_Quantity="3.00000000000000" ows_Quantity2="5.00000000000000" ows_Color="Orange" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_Title="Orange" ows_ID="1" ows_UniqueId="1;#{FEDE3004-A0F4-421F-A76B-5BD51003B11C}" ows_owshiddenversion="8" ows_FSObjType="1;#0" ows_Created_x0020_Date="1;#2012-08-01 19:24:08" ows_Created="2012-08-01 19:24:08" ows_FileLeafRef="1;#1_.000" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_Modified="2012-08-15 11:15:41" ows_FileRef="1;#Sandbox/bitest/Lists/Produce/1_.000" ows_MetaInfo="1;#"/>
                    <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_Year="2012" ows_LinkTitle="Apple" ows_Quantity="5.00000000000000" ows_Quantity2="9.00000000000000" ows_Color="Red" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_Title="Apple" ows_ID="2" ows_UniqueId="2;#{1E40887F-87BF-4029-93A3-A1096DF1D1A7}" ows_owshiddenversion="8" ows_FSObjType="2;#0" ows_Created_x0020_Date="2;#2012-08-01 19:24:42" ows_Created="2012-08-01 19:24:42" ows_FileLeafRef="2;#2_.000" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_Modified="2012-08-15 11:15:42" ows_FileRef="2;#Sandbox/bitest/Lists/Produce/2_.000" ows_MetaInfo="2;#"/>
                    <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_Year="2011" ows_LinkTitle="Orange" ows_Quantity="4.00000000000000" ows_Quantity2="9.00000000000000" ows_Color="Orange" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_Title="Orange" ows_ID="4" ows_UniqueId="4;#{D3C73386-1EA5-435A-BD1A-EF67F719078F}" ows_owshiddenversion="7" ows_FSObjType="4;#0" ows_Created_x0020_Date="4;#2012-08-15 11:13:23" ows_Created="2012-08-15 11:13:23" ows_FileLeafRef="4;#4_.000" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_Modified="2012-08-15 11:15:36" ows_FileRef="4;#Sandbox/bitest/Lists/Produce/4_.000" ows_MetaInfo="4;#"/>
                    <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_Year="2011" ows_LinkTitle="Apple" ows_Quantity="8.00000000000000" ows_Quantity2="12.0000000000000" ows_Color="Red" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_Title="Apple" ows_ID="5" ows_UniqueId="5;#{13F99513-8DE1-48A9-9114-40E5A8B2343F}" ows_owshiddenversion="6" ows_FSObjType="5;#0" ows_Created_x0020_Date="5;#2012-08-15 11:13:59" ows_Created="2012-08-15 11:13:59" ows_FileLeafRef="5;#5_.000" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_Modified="2012-08-15 11:15:27" ows_FileRef="5;#Sandbox/bitest/Lists/Produce/5_.000" ows_MetaInfo="5;#"/>
                    <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_Year="2010" ows_LinkTitle="Orange" ows_Quantity="2.00000000000000" ows_Quantity2="6.00000000000000" ows_Color="Orange" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_Title="Orange" ows_ID="6" ows_UniqueId="6;#{A6DBFD00-6383-4993-9C9E-4398E080FDEE}" ows_owshiddenversion="6" ows_FSObjType="6;#0" ows_Created_x0020_Date="6;#2012-08-15 11:14:05" ows_Created="2012-08-15 11:14:05" ows_FileLeafRef="6;#6_.000" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_Modified="2012-08-15 11:15:38" ows_FileRef="6;#Sandbox/bitest/Lists/Produce/6_.000" ows_MetaInfo="6;#"/>
                    <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_Year="2010" ows_LinkTitle="Apple" ows_Quantity="10.0000000000000" ows_Quantity2="2.00000000000000" ows_Color="Red" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_Title="Apple" ows_ID="7" ows_UniqueId="7;#{2F1BD539-545A-4796-AC1D-A9C4B76BE253}" ows_owshiddenversion="4" ows_FSObjType="7;#0" ows_Created_x0020_Date="7;#2012-08-15 11:14:58" ows_Created="2012-08-15 11:14:58" ows_FileLeafRef="7;#7_.000" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_Modified="2012-08-15 11:15:28" ows_FileRef="7;#Sandbox/bitest/Lists/Produce/7_.000" ows_MetaInfo="7;#"/>
                </rs:data>
            </listitems></GetListItemsResult></GetListItemsResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

"

The following routine is designed to iterate through this response and find associated values. It completely fails to execute as though the xData.XML is empty (I also tried xData.xml - no change).

```
$(xData.XML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
           quantityOneArray[i] = parseFloat($(this).attr("ows_Quantity"));
           quantityTwoArray[i] = parseFloat($(this).attr("ows_Quantity2"));
           i++;
           alert("xData "+ i + ": "+xData.XML);
    });
```

[Here is a link to a screenshot of my IE8 debugger](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v34/Shrout1/IE8_xData_Debugger.png) window with several watches. The `xData.xml` string is highlighted. This breakpoint immediately precedes my iteration routine above.

- Is my selector formatted incorrectly?
- Does my selector require additional escapes?
- Am I looking at the wrong return value or object?

I am absolutely pulling out my hair here. I changed the selector to "row" in Chrome and it works; in IE8 that makes no difference.

Also, take a look at [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/05/06/querying-sharepoint-list-items-using-jquery.aspx) to see a working example. Initially I was using "xData.responseXML" but it would show as "Undefined" in the debugger.

Comment: Is the xml parsed as an xml document before you try to traverse it? If the browsers are actually parsing them as html elements, that would absolutely make sense as IE8 doesn't allow elements that it doesn't recognize while chrome simply allows them.

Comment: @KevinB You're probably right; the blog post code seems to be accessing `.responseXML`. That isn't a valid property for me... What is the best way to parse this response? I'm still quite green on all this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are passing an xml string to `$()`, which would result in jQuery turning that xml string into HTML. Modern browsers tend to just allow it and go with the "new" html elements, while older browsers (IE6,7,8) choke on them.

Try using

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xData.XML);
$(xmlDoc).find("z\\:row").each(...
```

Comment: I'm getting back "null" for xmlDoc. Formatted it as you specified. :P

Comment: Is it supposed to be XML or xml. it does make a big difference.

Comment: Kevin, you are my own personal Jesus.

Comment: And it was "xml" not "XML" - I tested it initally but not in the changed code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Chrome/Firefox:

xml.children[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML

IE8+/Safari:

xml.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].textContent

IE8:

xml.documentElement.childNodes[1].text;

Sample code here,

var xml = $.parseXML(XMLDOC);

Var xmlNodeValue = "";

if(userAgent.match("msie 8.0")){

xmlNodeValue = xml.children[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML;

}else{ // IE8+

xmlNodeValue = xml.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].textContent;

}